# Notify the javascript in other html page

Tags: javascript

I just move from objective-c to javascript and develop html based app.
In objc, there are two ways for communication between ViewControllers.
1.protocol
2.post notification

Just wonder if there is same mechanism in javascript?

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you can look at HTML5's web messaging.

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/window-postmessage-messagechannel/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-document_messaging

Comment: Is it browser compatible? Is there a third party js framework to wrapper the different case of all web broswers

Comment: you could get that in the wiki. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-document_messaging#Support